# How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

If I go here

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

And click 'Launch demo modal' it does the expected thing.  I'm using the modal as part of my signup process and there is server side validation involved.  If there are problems I want to redirect the user to the same modal with my validation messages displayed.  At the moment I can't figure out how to get the modal to display other than a physical click from the user.  How can I launch the model programmatically?

Answer (score 434, accepted):

In order to manually show the modal pop up you have to do this

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

You previously need to initialize it with `show: false` so it won't show until you manually do it.

```
$('#myModal').modal({ show: false})
```

Where `myModal` is the id of the modal container.

Comment: Thanks. That worked out. One observation however is that, when I the modal box opens, it resets the scrolling and if I triggered the modal box from the bottom of page, the page gets scrolled to top. How should I stop that?

Comment: @tdubs: weird, it should work. See latest modal code https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js. So far I see, it should still working

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, I tried both in the console, I find that only one works  using chromium. $('#myModal').modal({show: false}) doesn't work but $('#myModal').modal('hide') works. Not sure why

Comment: Is there any way to pass a custom value or parameter as option like $('#myModel').model({data:1,show:false})

Comment: @AnupSharma: what for?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi In a situation when I need to pass any information to the model. Example: Say I have a tree Structure and I right click on any node and click Edit Details. And that triggers a modal with editable form and save to db using id stored in the node. now I need to pass this id to model using $('#myModal').modal({data:1}); but the problem is I can't access this value within Modal form

Comment: I'd say you can use standard `data()` jquery method: `$('#myModal').data('data', 1)` and then you can do `$('#myModal').data('data')` to get stored value. In any case, I recommend you to create a separated question since your problem is not related to original question :)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Sorry for the late response. I used a global variable to achieve this.

Comment: @divinedragon ages later I know, but the issue with scrolling to the top of the page is likely due to triggering the popup with a tag like `'<a href='#'>` and failing to `return false` or `preventDefault` inside the handler. The browser is doing as instructed and scrolling to the default anchor - the top of the page. I've had this bite me several times as our CSS sometimes relies on having a `href` set for the styling to match.

Answer (score 68):

You should't write **data-toggle="modal"** in the element which triggered the modal (like a button), and you  manually can show the modal with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and hide with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: I have a URL that opens the modal with data-toggle. Then inside the modal I have a button that calls a function which last thing it does is closing the modal using the hide method you suggest. Great!

Answer (score 35):

This is a code for Bootstrap **v5 without jQuery**.

```js
let myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {});
myModal.show();
```

### Demo

And this is a [codesandbox](https://idu6i.csb.app/) demo to open modal on page load programmatically.

[image]

https://idu6i.csb.app/

### Refs

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#show

Comment: Note to future readers: if you've configured the modal via the DOM with attributes already, it'd be best to use [`Modal.getOrCreateInstance()`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#passing-options) as this will prevent you from having to match the configuration of the modal via the DOM and JS

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for a programmatical modal creation, you might love this:

http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Even though Bootstrap's modal provides a javascript way for modal creation, you still need to write modal's html markups first.

Answer (score 13):

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/hLxauuaz/)

Answer (score 11):

you can show the model via jquery (javascript)

```
$('#yourModalID').modal({
  show: true
})
```

Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fVgqU/2/)

or you can just remove the class "hide"

```
<div class="modal" id="yourModalID">
  # modal content
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do this the `angular (2/4)` way, here is what I did:

```
<div [class.show]="visible" [class.in]="visible" class="modal fade" id="confirm-dialog-modal" role="dialog">
..
</div>`
```

Important things to **note**:

- `visible` is a variable (boolean) in the component which governs modal's visibility.
- `show` and `in` are bootstrap classes.

An example [component](https://github.com/nivite/nisdk/blob/master/projects/nlib/src/lib/nlib.component.ts#L31) & [html](https://github.com/nivite/nisdk/blob/master/projects/nlib/src/lib/nlib.component.html#L74)

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('rsvpModal', { static: false }) rsvpModal: ElementRef;
..
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onEscapeKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.hideRsvpModal();
  }
..
  hideRsvpModal(event?: Event) {
    if (!event || (event.target as Element).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.rsvpModal.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.rsvpModal.nativeElement, 'show');
      this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
    }
  }
  showRsvpModal() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.rsvpModal.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.rsvpModal.nativeElement, 'show');
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
  }
```

**Html**

```
<!--S:RSVP-->
<div class="modal fade" #rsvpModal role="dialog" aria-labelledby="niviteRsvpModalTitle" (click)="hideRsvpModal($event)">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="niviteRsvpModalTitle">

                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="hideRsvpModal()" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary bg-white text-dark"
                    (click)="hideRsvpModal()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--E:RSVP-->
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code useful to open modal on openModal() function and close on closeModal() :

```
      function openModal() {
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#myModal").modal();
          });
      }

     function closeModal () {
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#myModal").modal('hide');
          });  
      }
```

/* #myModal is the id of modal popup */

Comment: Please explain what the code does when posting answers.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. I wanted to open the Bootstrap modal by clicking on the table rows and get more details about each row. I used a trick to do this, Which I call the virtual button! Compatible with the latest version of Bootstrap (v5.0.0-alpha2). It might be useful for others as well.

See this code snippet with preview:
https://gist.github.com/alireza-rezaee/c60da1429c36351ef4f071dec0ea9aba

Summary:

```
let exampleButton = document.createElement("button");
exampleButton.classList.add("d-none");
document.body.appendChild(exampleButton);
exampleButton.dataset.toggle = "modal";
exampleButton.dataset.target = "#exampleModal";

//AddEventListener to all rows
document.querySelectorAll('#exampleTable tr').forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //Set parameteres (clone row dataset)
        exampleButton.dataset.whatever = e.target.closest('tr').dataset.whatever;
        //Button click simulation
        //Now we can use relatedTarget
        exampleButton.click();
    })
});
```

All this is to use the `relatedTarget` property. (See [Bootstrap docs](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content))

Comment: I had to use: `dataset.bsToggle` and `dataset.bsTarget` instead of `dataset.toggle` and `dataset.target`

Answer (score -1):

In javscript you can simulate a click on an invisible modal button?

HTML:

```
<a id="trigger" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" style="position:absolute;display:none;">
  Launch demo modal
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("trigger").click();
</script>
```

(work on bootstrap 5.3)

Comment: This is not a good solution. In this solution you need to create an invisible button which is bad practice. @kohheepeace solution is alot better!

Comment: Thanks @MartijnHiemstra I don't see.Why it's a bad practice?

Comment: Because you need to create an extra element do get the job done when it can be done with Javascript alone. Also making a button invisible and then clicking on it is useless. Why not just call the Javascript that opens the modal instead.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how you do it with ternary operator

```
$('#myModal').modal( variable === 'someString' ? 'show' : 'hide');
```