# Using twitter bootstrap modals as a view in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Does anyone know of a gem that would allow me to easily implement an action as a modal, without having to include modal markup on every page.

For instance, I want the 'new' action for one of my controllers to always be in a modal...

Basically I would love to be able to render the action as a modal such that I could go

```
def new
  render layout: "modal"
end
```

When I render `layout` here I do actually still want the main application layout loaded, but I also want another embedded layout (without having to use variables and render partials inside my view) which would wrap all of the required `.modal`, `.modal-dialog`, and `.modal-content` divs around the code in my new.html.erb template which would of course be something like

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4>Yay!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body clearfix">
  <p>Seamless modals rock!</p>
</div>
```

Any links to this action would be nothing out of the ordinary and not require the addition of `data-toggle` etc, and you could also visit the action by entering the url manually because when you `render layout: "modal"` rails also includes the `$('#myModal').modal('show')` wrapped in an `on.load` function or something similar and your modal is fired on page load. This could be made to work quite nicely with turbolinks.

This is a pretty specific example but I thought there might be something similar already built out there. I may be asking too much here.

All of these modal actions are within logged-in unindexed content, so I don't think it would matter in terms of SEO.

**UPDATE**

I have since decided that what I wanted would not really work nicely from a UX perspective, as the closer I got to my preferred solution, the more oddities arose such as:

- If I visit the action, the modal fires automatically but of course there is nothing behind the modal. What happens when I click cancel or the close button?
- When I submit my form in the modal and it posts back to the same action, sure it shows all of the errors nicely and without having to write javascript, but in the meantime the whole modal disappeared and reappeared.

Some of these could be fixed by using turbolinks and adding a whole host of extra options such as redirects and background views but it would probably take more time to fiddle around with than time it would save adding new modals.

Comment: If you are trying to embedd this into another layout everyime that layout is rendered, all you have to do is call render to your layot to embedd inside the master layout. I think that is what your looking for.

Comment: Hi @ITNinja thanks for your comment - though I am not sure I understand what you mean? Could you provide a simple code example?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting confused with how modals work:

---

**Modals**

Modals are nothing more than DIV elements on a page (with CSS / JS to make them appear to hover "over" the other content)

Bootstrap or not, they're still just an element which has to be rendered into a layout like everything else. The difference is you need to call them with CSS & JS to make them appear to float

---

**Code**

If you'd like to display your `new` action in a modal, do this:

1. Send a remote (ajax) request to the new action (from your link)
2. Handle the ajax request without a layout
3. In the original ajax request, render the returned data in a modal element

Here:

```
#app/views/your/action.html.erb
<%= link_to "New", new_modal_path, id: "modal_path" %>

#app/views/your/new.html.erb
<div id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Yay!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body clearfix">
        <p>Seamless modals rock!</p>
    </div>
</div>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def new
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render layout: !request.xhr? } #renders naked html if ajax
    end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
$("#modal_path").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href");
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).appendTo("body");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

[Good reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks Rich, your solution is essentially what I already had working. I know exactly what modals are and how they work. You didn't understand my question, which is my fault because I didn't word it well enough. I have amended my question a little and added an update.