# Keep Bootstrap Modal Open when page refresh

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap modal as a login window, and would like it remains open if user put wrong login info. My Page refreshed after submitting the form.Is there a way after refresh page modal open again and I an show the message there that Login Failed:Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to trigger the modal when there is an error after a post back.

You could have the server print out some javascript to trigger the modal after a post back ONLY on an error condition.  You didn't mention what server side technology you are using, so here is some psuedo server side code:

```
if (hasAuthenticationErrors) 
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     </script>
end if
```

That bit of javascript would have to be rendered AFTER the modal is initialized with a show:false option

```
$('#myModal').modal({ show: false})
```

see: [How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is certainly possible, but not even necessary. You should use the [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in order to withhold the form from submitting the page. That is, if you use AJAX, which looks to be the perfect place for it.

An example would be

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $('#form');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
            }
        });
    ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```