# trigger bootstrap modal via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

got a problem.
I am trying to trigger bootstrap modal via jquery and it doesnt work.
I tried every way:
way no1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#server_msg_modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

way no2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#server_msg_modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

way no3:

```
$('#server_msg_modal').modal({
    show: 'true'
});
```

nothing is working...
please help me.

Comment: Did you include the Bootstrap JavaScript source after including jQuery?

Comment: yes and if i try to trigger in via html its working  the html: <div class="btn-danger" href="#server_msg_modal" data-toggle="modal" id="btn">press me</div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your jQuery function to add the click handler to the button, and to open the modal window should both work. See the example below. I can only suggest you to take a look at for example Chrome's DevTools to see if you have any JavaScript errors in its console.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#server_msg_modal').modal('show');
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-danger" href="#server_msg_modal" data-toggle="modal">using data attribute</div>

<div class="btn btn-danger" id="btn">using jQuery click handler</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="server_msg_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: this code doesn't  work for me at all.... I am using adobe dreamweaver... any idea why?

Comment: ok, I deleted all the code and wrote everything again and i guess it workes fine. thanks for the help