# Bootstrap Modal not opening (trigger) on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues with a modal that i have. I searched a lot, i found some similar issues with  `data-target="#panel-modal2"` where there was no `#`, but mine seems O.K. Any help?

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-red btn-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-modal2">Transfer</a>
</div><!--.btn-group-->


<div class="modal modal-nutrition fade full-height from-right" id="panel-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Transfer</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
          <div class="row margin-top-30">
            <div class="col-md-3">To:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                <option>- Select -</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row margin-top-30">
            <div class="col-md-3">Date:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></span>
                    <div class="inputer">
                      <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="transferDate" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" value="03/18/2013" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="note note-info note-left-striped">

            </div><!--.note-->
          </div><!--.col-md-12-->
        </div><!--.row-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You didn't describe your problem well enough. Can you include more details on your questions?

Comment: Well, when i click on the `<a class="btn btn-red btn-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-modal2">Transfer</a>` , the modal didn't trigger

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just a copy and paste issue, but I think you might be missing a closing `</div>` tag at the end

Comment: all divs are correctly opened and closed

Comment: So copy and paste issue? When I grab the code you posted I can see that this div: `<div class="modal modal-nutrition fade full-height from-right"` has not been closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trigger bootstrap modal via jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250009/trigger-bootstrap-modal-via-jquery)

Comment: I am seeing this problem, works fine on Desktop works fine on mobile browser using desktop mode, works fine in mobile mode without the select on the popup, have a modal popup with a select and it says "nope" no error no nothing just will not open the modal, just wondering if the select makes the selection a popup as mobile jquery doesnt allow popups on popups

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution was changing the buttons' attributes.

As you will see inside the HTML starter template example from Bootstrap's Website (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#static-backdrop), the Modal buttons have attributes like:

- data-bs-toggle
- data-bs-toggle

If the attributes include **-bs-** in the middle, try removing it:

- data-toggle
- data-toggle

If they don't include it, then try including it.

Comment: this saved my day, it's weird why it's implemented this way. any idea?

Comment: Glad to see it's been helpful. It's probably a mismatch between the HTML attribute and JS code.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding bootstrap.js in your script tag. Also add jquery.js before the bootstrap.js

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-red btn-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-modal2">Transfer</a>
                                </div><!--.btn-group-->


<div class="modal modal-nutrition fade full-height from-right" id="panel-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Transfer</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">From:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">Nursery</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-top-30">
                    <div class="col-md-3">To:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                            <option>- Select -</option>
                            <option>Nursery</option>
                            <option>Toddlers</option>
                            <option>Other kindergarten</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-top-30">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Date:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <div class="inputer">
                                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="transferDate" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" value="03/18/2013" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="note note-info note-left-striped">
                        <h4>Active Transfer</h4>
                        <p>This person will transfer to Nursery on 14.05.2016</p>
                        <p>If you submit a new transfer the active one will be overwrited.</p>
                    </div><!--.note-->
                </div><!--.col-md-12-->
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add default jquery and boostrap js your modal popup will work fine. Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-red btn-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-modal2">Transfer</a>
</div><!--.btn-group-->


<div class="modal modal-nutrition fade full-height from-right" id="panel-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Transfer</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">From:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">Nursery</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row margin-top-30">
            <div class="col-md-3">To:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                <option>- Select -</option>
                <option>Nursery</option>
                <option>Toddlers</option>
                <option>Other kindergarten</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row margin-top-30">
            <div class="col-md-3">Date:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></span>
                    <div class="inputer">
                      <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="transferDate" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" value="03/18/2013" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="note note-info note-left-striped">
              <h4>Active Transfer</h4>
              <p>This person will transfer to Nursery on 14.05.2016</p>
              <p>If you submit a new transfer the active one will be overwrited.</p>
            </div><!--.note-->
          </div><!--.col-md-12-->
        </div><!--.row-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, i added default jquery and bootstrap at my last line in html, still doesn't work

Comment: Does console show any error? Does the bootstrap js and default jquery having new version?

Comment: No, no error. I'm getting last version of bootstrap, i have similar modal in another page, there works fine

Comment: That's strange. If  you have included default jquery and bootsrap js it should work fine as such you modal popup code is perfect. First you have included default jquery and then bootstrap js?

Comment: Yes, that's the order

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're using a too old or too new version of jquery for bootstrap v3.x.x requirements. Check that your jquery version (max) is 2.2.4, because your code is fine, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-red btn-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-modal2">Transfer</a>
                                </div><!--.btn-group-->


<div class="modal modal-nutrition fade full-height from-right" id="panel-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Transfer</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">From:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">Nursery</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-top-30">
                    <div class="col-md-3">To:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                            <option>- Select -</option>
                            <option>Nursery</option>
                            <option>Toddlers</option>
                            <option>Other kindergarten</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-top-30">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Date:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <div class="inputer">
                                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="transferDate" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" value="03/18/2013" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="note note-info note-left-striped">
                        <h4>Active Transfer</h4>
                        <p>This person will transfer to Nursery on 14.05.2016</p>
                        <p>If you submit a new transfer the active one will be overwrited.</p>
                    </div><!--.note-->
                </div><!--.col-md-12-->
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For  elements, omit data-target, and use href="#modalID" instead;

Answer (score 0):

Change the button attribute from
`data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`  and
`data-target` to `data-bs-target`