# Can't display a modal by clicking the image

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a test modal, so that I want it to be opened whenever we click the image, but it doesn't work, it opens another page with #myModal at the end of the url. What should I do to solve this?

Here is my test modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title">This is the header</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is the modal body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my list, including the image:

```
<div class="news-items-wrapper">
          <div class="news-wrapper" *ngFor="let item of section.items">
            <div class="news-item-wrapper">
              <a class="thumb" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"
                 [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.thumbnail + ')'}">
              </a>
              <div class="info">
                <a class="title" [href]="item.youtube" target="_blank">{{ item.title }}</a>
                <div class="description" [innerHTML]="item.description"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I also tried to open it with button, but still not working
              `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">click</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide code I use, and hopefully it will help you.

Try and see if you added this to your image or a button:

```
data-target="#show-details-modal" data-toggle="modal"
```

An example of what I did:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#show-details-modal" data-toggle="modal">Display text goes here</a>
```

Then use the following modal:

```
<div id="show-details-modal" class="modal fade" style="width:100%">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                <div id="loadingPanelShowDetails" class="col-md-12 text-center" style="display: none;">
                    <br />
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 100%">...LOADING...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="target-show-details">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also try referencing the following on the page where your modal is:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still it switches to another link with # at the end. 
I think the problem is related to the version of the bootstrap or smth like that.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try adding the references I added at the bottom of my answer and see if that helps ?

Comment: Here is the link I got it from, hope it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225363/bootstrap-modal-not-opening-trigger-on-click