# trigger login modal via jquery

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to trigger login modal via jQuery and it does not work.
 
I didn't understand why the modal didn't popup? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250009/trigger-bootstrap-modal-via-jquery) is a similar question and follow the answer although didn't solve the problem.

```js
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login').click(function () {
          $('#loginModal').modal('show');
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<button id="#login" class="btn btn-danger">
  click me
</button>
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I heartily thank if anyone helps me to figure it out. [Here](https://codepen.io/falamiw2/pen/oNjBJqa) is my codepen link in case you need.

Comment: Do you check console for error?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

```
<button id="#login" class="btn btn-danger">
  click me
</button>
```

You have extra `#` in `id` attribute:

rewrite like this:

```
<button id="login" class="btn btn-danger">
  click me
</button>
```