# Load ajax modal via setInterval

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to open Reminder Modal but alert is working and modal is not working even i check errors in console.log() but there isn't any error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadlink1(){
        $("#reminderDiv").empty();
        $("#reminderDiv").load("{!! URL::to('admin/remindercheck') !!}",function(data){
          // $(this).unwrap();
        if (data == 0){
          alert('alert');
          $('*[data-toggle="notifications-modal"]').click();
          $('#notifications-modal').modal('show');
          if($('#notifications-modal').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') return;
        }
      });
      var refreshstatus = $('#reminderStatus').val();

    }
    setInterval(function(){
      loadlink1();
    },30000);
});
```

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notifications-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notifications-modal" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
               <h2 class="modal-title pcConv-title"></h2>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body pcConv-modal-body">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

PS: Modal code exit in a body tag Modal working fine via button click.

Comment: put debugger; before showing modal, does it reach there?

Comment: i added alert and its working and added console.log too working fine but modal not firing

Comment: Why you have `.click()`? Is `notifications-modal` a sure valid `id`? what you are doing with `aria-hidden` check? Add some html too if possible!

Comment: i got .click from stack but this doesn't work... yes id is valid.. i think aria.-hidden is by default i removed in my file and checked this doesn't work too

Comment: could you please provide a fiddle which reproduces the issue?

Comment: try trigger clicking the button since you said that its working via button click instead of click .... $( "#button id" ).trigger( "click" ); . I know that's not a good solution but it does the job

Comment: @Rinor Dreshaj trigger doesnt solve the problem... e

Comment: @code-jaff unable to create jsfiddle because i dont how to use ajax in fiddl

Comment: if(data == 0 ) {  $('#myModal').modal('show'); } You previously need to initialize it with show: false so it won't show until you manually do it.  $('#myModal').modal({ show: false}) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically

Comment: @ Rinor Dreshaj i dont want to show it manually i want when $data == 0 then it show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.ajax() Try my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      // var refreshstatus = $('#reminderStatus').val();
      $.ajax({
        type     : "GET",
        url      : "{!! URL::to('admin/remindercheck') !!}",
        cache    : false,
        success  : function(data) {
          if (data == 0){
            $('#notifications-modal').modal('show');
          }
            // $('#noti-counter').html(data).show('slow');
        }
      });
    },30000);
});
});
```