# Bootstrap 3 - load modal with predefined body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am running a JS function after which I want to show a modal asking the user a predefined question.

Since the modal will be loaded as a result of a previous AJAX success or error result, I am not launching the modal via a button click of some sorts, hence have nothing to attach the modal-body update to attach to. How would I do this?

Basically, I am trying to achieve this:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html('<p>this is a test</p>');
});
```

in this way:
// show alert modal to inform user of

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#mod_output').html(data);
    drawVisualization();


    // show alert modal to inform user of 
    $("#AlertModal").modal();
    $("AlertModal").find(".modal-body").html('<p>this is a test</p>');
}
```

thanks

Comment: trigger modal on AJAX success

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically

Comment: @Dherya no success with `$('#AlertModal .modal-body').html('test');     $.('#AlertModal').modal('show');`