# By getting input 1 or 2 from user and clicking the enter button model should be change based on the input

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

USing script to get the input value from input box and there are two different models named model1s and model2s , user should give either 1 or 2 based on that the model should popup , while clicking enter button.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {       
     var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
     var abcd= document.getElementById('abcd'); 
     abcd.data-target = "model" + input + "s";          
  }
</script>

<div class="col-lg-3">
   <input type="text" placeholder="123" id="input" required>
   <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" class="btn btn-info" id="abcd">ENTER</button>
</div>

<div id="model1s" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">    
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>    

<div id="model2s" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">     
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You means to say you want to open model from the input box value? For example if i type model2s and press enter, it should be open modelbox model2s?

Comment: yes , actually i want do that only but here i am trying to give input as 1 or 2  based on that data-target value will change @Ghanshyam Bhava

Comment: I think @prasad and Ninja already done what you want. check his snippet.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , now it works fine@GhanshyamBhava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your code, you need to add

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

     var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
     var abcd= document.getElementById('abcd'); 
     //abcd.data-target = "model" + input + "s";
     $("#model" + input + "s").modal('show');

}
</script>
```

also, you need to check below link

[How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Comment: I tried your solution also , It worked fine , thanks @smith shah

Answer (score 1):

Please see this fiddle, this is a general solution to this question. http://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/1aeur58f/225/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#mymodal').on('click',function(){
    var id = $('#input').val();
  $('#myModal'+id).modal('show');
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks , you save my time

Comment: @saravanakumar you are welcome. Please accept this answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this  `querySelectorAll()` .first hide all the `modal` box then match the given input value `modal` box to show

```js
function myFunction() {

  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var abcd = document.getElementById('abcd');
  document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(function(a){
  a.style.display='none';
  })
  document.getElementById("model" + input + "s").style.display='block';


}
```

```css
.modal{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="123" id="input" required>
  <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" class="btn btn-info" id="abcd">ENTER</button>
</div>



<div id="model1s" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div id="model2s" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal2 Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```