# Invoke bootstrap modal when php if condition is satisfied

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to display bootstrap 3 modal (not using onclick button) when some condition is satisfied in php.. I am new in php. I want to display a bootstrap modal if the book is return with fine. I am new in php bootstrap 3 and I am really confusing to this problem.
php codes:-

```
<?php
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim('now()'));
if (isset($_POST['return'])) {
    try {
        //--- start if else
        if (isset($_POST['acc_no']) && !empty($_POST['acc_no'])) {
            $acc_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['acc_no']));
            //echo "$acc_no";
        } else {
            throw new Exception('<p class="notice">Please Enter an Accession Number.</p>');
        }
        //-----end of if else

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `issue_tbl` WHERE `acc_no`='$acc_no' AND /*`member_no`='$member_no' AND*/ `issue_return_status`='issued'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) < 1) {
            throw new Exception('<p class="notice">No Book Issue found for this Accession Number.</p>');
        } else {
            $row          = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $title        = $row['title'];
            $acc_no       = $row['acc_no'];
            $issue_date   = $row['issue_date'];
            $cover_img    = $row['cover_img'];
            $author       = $row['author'];
            //no of days ,weeks
            $issue_on     = strtotime($issue_date);
            $current_date = time();
            $no_of_days   = $current_date - $issue_on;
            $no_of_days   = round($no_of_days / (60 * 60 * 24));
            $weeks        = $no_of_days / 7;
            //$weeks= round($weeks);
            $total_fine   = $weeks * 5;
            $total_fine   = round($total_fine, 2);
            //$total_fine=round($total_fine);
            if ($no_of_days <= 7) {
                $due_status = '<h1 class="label label-success">No Due</h1>';
                $total_fine = '0.00';
                $sql        = "UPDATE `issue_tbl` SET `issue_return_status`='return',`return_date`=$date WHERE `acc_no`='$acc_no' AND /* `member_no`='$member_no' AND */ `issue_return_status`='issued'";
                $res        = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$res) {
                    throw new Exception('<p class="notice">Failed to Return Book.</p>');
                } else {
                    $acc_update_sql = "UPDATE `acc_reg` SET `available`='true' WHERE `acc_no`= '$acc_no' AND `available`='false'";
                    if (mysqli_query($conn, $acc_update_sql)) {
                        echo '<p class="notice-success">Book Returned Successfully.</p>';
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn));
                    }
                }
                // throw new Exception($due_status);
            } else {
                $due_status = ' <h1 class="label label-danger"> Fine Due</h1>';
                // I want to display Bootstrap modal in this section just like i am using javascript alert in the below...

                // -------------------------------------- I want do this without modal button-------------------
                // <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                // echo' <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                //                                Launch demo modal
                //                                </button>';
                // -------------------------------------- I want do this without modal button-------------------
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
                echo '</script>';
                throw new Exception($due_status);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception $e) { //end of try block
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } //end of catch block
} //end of Isset post issue
?>
```

modal :-

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Please someone help me. sorry for my bad English. its not my first language. thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically

Comment: In addition to what @ju_ pointed to, you need to understand the following principle: php is executed when the page is being "baked" (on server side). Bootstrap opens via JavaScript, when the page is complete and already served to browser (client side). When your condition is true (in php) you need to place something in the page HTML markup  (like a `data-` attribute), that you can check via JavaScript after the page reaches the browser. If the element/attribute you passed is true, open your modal programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're just starting, I decided to add some detail to my comment under your question and transform it into an answer, giving you more detailed explanations, in the hope you (and other future users) might find it useful. Here's my original comment, which outlines the principle: *php* is **server side** and *JavaScript* is **client-side**:

> In addition to what @ju_ pointed to, you need to understand the following principle: php is executed when the page is being "baked" (on server side). Bootstrap opens via JavaScript, when the page is complete and already served to browser (client side). When your condition is true (in php) you need to place something in the page HTML markup (like a `data-*` attribute), that you can check via JavaScript after the page reaches the browser. If the element/attribute you passed is true, open your modal programmatically.

---

Understanding the logic of your `php` code is irrelevant here. I will simply assume you placed the truthfulness of your condition inside a variable in php called `$isConditionTrue`. In php:

```
if ($isConditionTrue) {
    echo '<div style="display:none" data-condition></div>'
}
```

This will place a hidden div in your markup that will have a `data-condition` attribute.

In JavaScript (I'll use jQuery, since it's already loaded for Bootstrap):

```
if ($("[data-condition]").is("[data-condition]")) {
    $('#yourModal').modal('show');
}
```

Note: don't forget to adjust the code that opens the modal with one that works on your particular modal. Also note `data-condition` is a pretty generic attribute, you might want to use a more specific one (hence less likely to conflict with other existing custom attributes, i.e.: `data-bookfine`, or `data-myfinebook`, etc...)

The condition basically checks if there is any element in your page with `data-condition` attribute. The solution above assumes you only use this technique with one element. If you plan to use it more than once, you might want to add values to `data-condition` or maybe classes and ids to the hidden elements, and adjust the JavaScript `if()`s so the logic works correctly for each case and does not affect the other cases.

---

Another note: you're not limited to `data-*` attributes, but it's a commonly used way to add custom logic to markup. It's also easily accessible via `.data()` method in jQuery, particularly useful when you have collections, so a lot of people use it. But you could use any valid HTML markup. For example, custom tags:

```
<book-fine></book-file>
```

but don't forget to go `book-fine{display:none}` in your CSS and change the JS to:

```
if ($('book-fine').is('book-fine')) { 
  // open modal
}
```