# Open Bootstrap 4 Modal via JavaScript by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a modal when I click on a link.
Unfortunately I couldn't change the HTML of the link. I could only change the content of `href`.

Like this:

```
<a href="#Modal">Open modal</a>
```

I could not add data-attributes or any other HTML.

In the docs I found a way to open the modal via JavaScript. I added this code to my site:

```
$('#Modal').modal();
```

It works but the modal opens immediately after the page loads.
I need it to open after I click on the link.

Is there a way to do this?

Here's my modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="h5 modal-title" id="ModalTitle">Modal Title</p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#Modal')` refers to an element with `id="Modal"`.

Comment: OK, I could add `id="Modal"` but that doens't help :-(

Comment: Cray did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURII tried that already but it doesn't work

Comment: @Cray can you add your html and js.

Comment: done, I added the code of my modal

Comment: Try to find the same question. But all answer not in javascript as mentioned in the question, but jquery

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Trigger click event on `a[href$="#Modal"]`.

```js
$('a[href$="#Modal"]').on( "click", function() {
   $('#Modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<a href="#Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open modal</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

EIDT: changed myModal to Modal

Comment: That's it! But I had to change myModal to Modal

Answer (score 3):

> need it to open after I click on the link.

So you'll need to check if the link is clicked.

jQuery provides many ways to select an element. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('a[href$="#Modal"]').on( "click", function() {
   $('#Modal').modal();
});`
```

Comment: I saw you already got a correct answer but i just wanted to be sure. https://jsfiddle.net/Ldnzn5bn/ Is a working example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>


$('a').on( "click", function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: as I wrote in my question, I'm not able to use a button or change the html of my link-tag