# Bootstrap data-toggle modal content within a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm new to programming, and I have this simple question but I can't figure out how to do it.

I got this working code from [Boostrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But instead of having a button I want to create a function to fire up the modal content:

```
function openModal(){
  /* DESCRIPTION: Open the warning modal */
   // data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
}
```

But I don't know how to the same thing as `data-toggle` and 
`data-target` do in the button click.

Someone has a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the Bootstrap JS api for the modal ( Link attached at the end of this answer ).

Here is the straight answer :-)

```
function openModal(){
   /* DESCRIPTION: Open the warning modal */
   $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
```

}

Here is another SO question related to this : [How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Here is a detailed link on Bootstrap official documentation  on various javascript methods for modals.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line in your function:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Note: remember to replace your modal id with myModal.