# Bootstrap V5 manually call a modal myModal.show() not working (vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

whats the correct way to manually call a modal in bootstrap 5?

i want to show the modal when page is open. i tried this:

my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        ... 
        ... 
        ... 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my script is

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal');
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
   
    myModal.show();
}
```

but got this error in console log:

```
 myModal.show is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.document.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have jquery - `show()` is a jquery specific thing.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404777/7058111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404777/7058111)

Comment: im using bootstrap v5 not v4.. v5 is supposed to be pure javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger a Bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404711/how-can-i-trigger-a-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Comment: sorry, forgot to add on my question that i need a pure javascript on this.

Comment: Try with: var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));

Comment: @Symphonic answer is correct one, y dont you post a comment, he/she will choose your answer and Symphonic if you want me to remove my answer i will.

Comment: hi guys, i just got your answer.. will try it right now.. thanks.. get back to you soon..

Comment: @Symphonic  -  its solves my problem. thanks so much..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> The modal plugin toggles your hidden content on demand, via data attributes or JavaScript. It also adds .modal-open to the  to override default scrolling behavior and generates a .modal-backdrop to provide a click area for dismissing shown modals when clicking outside the modal. [[source]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#usage)

**How to use via Vanilla JavaScript**

> Create a modal with a single line of JavaScript:
>
> `var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)`

[source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript)

*A quick example:*

```js
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), {});
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  myModal.show();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />


    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="exampleModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript and dependencies -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*As for your code,* you didn't follow the right way to show/toggle a modal in Vanilla JavaScript. Why did you expect `myModal.show()` to happen while `myModal` is just a DOM element?

Comment: you source link has an issue.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Is that only bootstrap 4/5 update? In 3rd version i was able to call modals by el.modal(“show”)…

Answer (score 35):

1. Create a new instace of modal and then call show method(see usage points)

> ```
> var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'))
> myModal.show()
> ```

[image]

ref: https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options

note: Bootstrap v5 no more uses jquery, instead it uses javascript. lots of changes are there in bootstrap v5, if you are working for a company and willing to use Bootstrap v5 then please go through all the changes.

Comment: exactly the answer I'm looking for but how can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: This is documented in bootstrap v5. 
Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Answer (score 23):

**Do the following If you use Bootstrap 5+ via `<script src="..." ></script>`**

```
let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('myModal')) // Returns a Bootstrap modal instance
// Show or hide:
modal.show();
modal.hide();
```

See more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getorcreateinstance

Bring BS to your page as shown here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: getOrCreateInstance method is especially useful now when you got tired from error that can't called something prior initialization.

Comment: After spending many hours trying to get modals to work in Vue3, this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Why on earth has this documentation been removed from the v5.2 version of the [Modal page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal)?

Answer (score 13):

Based on the javascript code provided by the OP I think the actual goal here is to **reach out the component by the DOM element**. I have also looked for a way to do this so wanted to share what I have found(or not found).

**v4-** It was possible and commonly used with the earlier versions. In v4 we could have used it easily with jQuery although the component is initialized by the data attributes and not directly from js.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

**v5.0.0-beta2** In the new version, a very promising api example is provided at the docs for another type of component. However, it does not seem to be working currently. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#asynchronous-functions-and-transitions)

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal')
var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModal) 
console.log(modal) // null
```

Since all the components are using same basecomponent, one might think that it is possible to get instance of the modal as well as the others like dropdown, collapse, carousel and all by using getInstance api method but it is not possible. At least for the current beta version.

A final note: It is still possible to include jQuery before v5 script and achive this.(https://codepen.io/cadday/pen/Jjbvxvm)

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(jQuery('#myModal').modal('show'));
}
```

Comment: In order for bootstrap.Modal.getInstance to work, you need to have created the instance. 
To do this, you have to do "new bootstrap.Modal(myModal)" preferably when the modal is created.

Comment: you thouch me that to find a element we use `$('#myModal')` in jquery and `$('#exampleModal').modal('show');` this will show the modal `$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');` will close the modal

Answer (score 5):

I've also searched for a solution to auto-open the modal on page load and solved it in the following solution.
You be able to add an **data-auto-open** attribute to the normal bootstrap syntax if you want to have it auto-opened. If the attribute is not set, is the modal working in the standard way as well.

I've added also an option to temporarily remove the **fade** effect if you want to have it open instantly after the page load. To make it happen is it just necessary to use **data-auto-open="instant"** instead of the empty **data-auto-open** attribute. After it's closed once and you want to re-open it manually will it have the fade effect again.

The working solution in TypeScript for **Bootstrap 5.0.0-Beta3** would be like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const selector = '[data-auto-open]';
    const modalElement: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (!modalElement) {
        return;
    }

    const mode = modalElement.dataset.autoOpen;
    const fade = modalElement.classList.contains('fade');

    if (fade && mode === 'instant') {
        modalElement.classList.remove('fade');
    }

    const modal = new Modal(modalElement, {});

    if (fade && mode === 'instant') {
        // There's currently a bug in the backdrop when the fade class 
        // will be added directly after the modal was opened to have the
        // close animation
        // modalElement.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        modalElement.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
            modalElement.classList.add('fade');
        }, {once : true});
    }

    modal.show();
}, {once : true});
```

The HTML would be the standard one:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-auto-open>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    Example Modal title
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Bootstrap 5]**

Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap’s individual js/dist/*.js), or all at once using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js (don’t include both).

If you use a bundler (Webpack, Rollup…), you can use /js/dist/*.js files which are UMD ready.

For Example, if you want to import only the Modal plugin from Bootstrap 5 you can do it:

Add the import statement at the top of your js file

```
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
```

And then show the modal when click on a button element for instance:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById('my-button-id');
const myModal  = document.getElementById('my-modal-id');

const modal = new Modal(myModal); // Instantiates your modal

myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.show(); // shows your modal
});
```

Comment: the best is `import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';` because is possible for use modal, with no npm install boostrap, just using CDN. solved. tks

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to do it

```
new bootstrap.Modal($('#MyModal')).show();
```

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: The main advantage of BS5 is that it no longer has to deal with junquery...

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to open/show a modal dialog in Bootstrap 5 is to create a link in your HTML to do it (it can be invisible), and then create/trigger a click event on the link.

Here is an example:

A link to open a modal dialog:

```
<a id=test data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#MODAL-ID"></a>
```

The JavaScript code to trigger the click event on this link:

```
triggerEvent(test,'click');

function triggerEvent(el,evName)
    {el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(evName,{}));}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'))

const circle = document.querySelector('#circle');
const modalTitle = document.querySelector('.modal-title');
const modalBtnEmpleado = document.querySelector('#modal-btn-empleado');


circle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    modalTitle.innerHTML = "jopo"
    modalBtnEmpleado.innerHTML = "jajajja"
    myModal.show()
})
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <span id="circle" class="material-icons float-start me-2 mt-5">
            add_circle
            </span>
      </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button id="modal-btn-empleado" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).